# How to turn `''` into `Null` in PHP to send variables to the sql store procedure?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and SQL Server. I have a store procedure for search customer. When I run with Null value it return 0 rows. It should be return all of the data.
This below is my code in my controller to run the store procedure:

```
$name = $request['name'];
$email = $request['email'];
$lower_age = $request['lower_age'];
$upper_age = $request['upper_age'];
$gender = $request['gender'];
$maritalstatus = $request['maritalstatus'];

$search = DB::select("EXEC dbo.search '".$name."', 
    '".$email."',
    '".$lower_age."',
    '".$upper_age."',
    '".$gender."',
    '".$maritalstatus."'"
);
```

This is when I print_r my store procedure:

> EXEC dbo.search '', '', '', '', '', ''

I need `''` become `NULL` like this below:

> EXEC dbo.search NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

Do you know how?

Comment: please also consider using parameters to build your query, this might be open for sql-injection

Answer (score 3):

```
".($lower_age === '' ? 'null' : "'$lower_age'").",
```